# Disable Wordpress plugin's JavaScript

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Is it possible to prevent the loading of a plugin's JavaScript in the Wordpress admin area, or on a specific page of the admin area?

For example, I have a plugin which breaks my media uploader, and the problem due to it's large JavaScript file which I can not track down.

Comment: Turn the plugin off or comment out the code in the plugin that adds the JS.

Comment: Usually the plugin author enqueues the JS (best way to do it). That way you can dequeue it.

Comment: Improved grammar/spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for `wp_enqueue_script` (if you are cli-savvy, you can use `grep -R "wp_enqueue_script /path/to/project/root`) in your plugin or theme files, then add to the bottom of **functions.php**:

```
// Deregister some scripts:
function deregister_scripts() {
      // Deregistering jQuery:
      wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

      if(is_front_page() ) :
        // Deregistering some script on Front page
        wp_deregister_script( 'some-script' );
      endif;  

      if(is_page(25) ) :
        // Deregistering script on page which's ID is 25
        wp_deregister_script( 'some-another-script' );
      endif;

      if(is_admin() ) :
        // Deregistering script on admin
        wp_deregister_script( 'yet-another-script' );
      endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'deregister_scripts' );
```